# How do I get the default value of an Enum using a non-generic Type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a method that iterates through an object's properties and sets the values to their type's default values.  Some properties are enums.  I have another function that gets the default value of the enum (not 0), but it requires passing the enum type which is not known in the current method.

```
    [DefaultValue(Red)]
    public enum Colors
    {
        Red = 1,
        green = 2
    }

    // In another class
    public static TEnum GetDefaultValue<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct
    {
        Type t = typeof(TEnum);
        DefaultValueAttribute[] attributes = (DefaultValueAttribute[])t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), false);
        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
        {
        return (TEnum)attributes[0].Value;
        }
        else
        {
        return default(TEnum);
        }
    }


    public static void ClearObject<T>(object obj)
    {
        obj = (T)obj;

        PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        string propName = "";

        try
        {
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in props)
        {
            propName = pi.Name;

            Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType;
            if (t.IsEnum)
            {
            //  This works
            //  var val = EnumFunctions.GetDefaultValue<Colors>();

            // The error is here
            var val = EnumFunctions.GetDefaultValue<t>();
            //                                     ^^^

            pi.SetValue(obj, val);
            }
            // In case of nullable value types int,datetime, etc - set null  
            else if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) != null)
            pi.SetValue(obj, null);
            else
            pi.SetValue(obj, null, null);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        string msg = $"Error for {propName}: {e.Message}";
        throw new Exception(msg);
        }
    }
```

I've tried `typeof(t)`, `t.GetType()`.

I want the default value for a Colors enum property to be Red.  The line causing the error is

```
var val = EnumFunctions.GetDefaultValue<t>();
Error   CS0118  't' is a variable but is used like a type
```

Comment: If you have an object and you want to meticulously inspect every property and change it back to its default value ("clear" it) then it might be 100x times easier to just replace the object with a new instance of the object. If anything about the object makes that impossible or impractical then it might be 99x easier to change the class so that you *can* do that, and then just create a new instance of the object. Or consider how many types of object you have to do this with. It might be far easier and more reliable to write a different "clear" function for each class.

Comment: What's very likely to happen is that you'll write this function, and then end up passing an object with some weird condition you didn't account for - something that your reflection doesn't look for, or some property that you wish was cleared differently. Then "clearing" that object will introduce a defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need generics here

```
public static object GetDefaultValue(Type type)
{
    DefaultValueAttribute[] attributes = (DefaultValueAttribute[])type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), false);
    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        return attributes[0].Value;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then you use it like this

```
 var val = EnumFunctions.GetDefaultValue(t);
 if(val != null)
     pi.SetValue(obj, val);
```

Source of your confusion:

Generally speaking, generics are not runtime construct, they're compile-time construct, so you can't use them in reflection, because reflection works at run time.

Comment: You can use generics in reflection, just as usual reflection but with additional MakeGeneric calls

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and informative answer.  I used your code and added to it.  My goal was to instantiate an object with default values - including DateTime properties set to DateTime.Now.  Here is what I came up with.  I'm open to suggestions on cleaning this up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also invoke the method with reflection like this:

```
typeof(EnumFunctions).GetMethod("GetDefaultValue").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above (thought I could post code).  I also wanted to ensure that enums were instantiated to a valid value.  Some enums do not have a 0 so the default of numeric types wouldn't work.

```
public MyClass() 
{
    // Sets default property values for all but dates
    Basefunctions.Clear<InternalExaminer>(this);

    // Sets default values by [DefalutValue()] tag.
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this))
    {
        pd.ResetValue(this);
    }

    // Sets date properties to current date.
    Basefunctions.SetDates<MyClass>(this);
}

public static class Basefunctions
{
    public static void SetDates<T>(object obj)
    {
        string propName = "";

        try
        {
            obj = (T)obj;

            PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                           .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)).ToArray();
            if (props != null)
            {
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in props)
                {
                    propName = pi.Name;
                    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) == null)
                        pi.SetValue(obj, date);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Could not set date for {propName}.\n{e.Message}");
        }
    }

    public static void Clear<T>(object obj)
    {
        obj = (T)obj;

        PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        string propName = "";

        try
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in props)
            {
                propName = pi.Name;

                Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType;

                if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) != null)
                    pi.SetValue(obj, null);
                else
                {
                    var val = GetDefaultVal(t);
                    if (t.IsEnum)
                    {
                        // In case enum does not have a 0
                        if (!Enum.IsDefined(t, val))
                            val = EnumMin(pi.PropertyType);
                    }
                    pi.SetValue(obj, val);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string msg = $"Error for {propName}: {e.Message}";
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
    }

    private static object GetDefaultVal(Type type)
    {
        DefaultValueAttribute att = (DefaultValueAttribute)type.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute));

        if (att != null)
            return att.Value;
        else
            return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
    }

    private static object EnumMin(Type t)
    {
        Array x = Enum.GetValues(t);
        var ret = x.GetValue(0);
        return ret;
    }

    private static object EnumMax(Type t)
    {
        Array x = Enum.GetValues(t);
        var ret = x.GetValue(x.Length - 1);
        return ret;
    }
}
```